# FIREBASE - average time between install and uninstall (first-open and app-remove)

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, appstats

I am wondering if there is a way to obtain from Firebase Analytics statistics **the average time spent from users between the two events of "first-open"** (that could be interpreted as *installation*) **and the relative potential "app-remove"** (*uninstallation*).

Considering it's an average calculated on "deviceID" or on "InstallationID" basees, i think there should be a calculated metric but i'm not finding it anywhere.

Thank you for your help.